# Java - sc.nextDouble() - make another line

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Sorry for my English but it is not my native language. I have to create program to calculate some math equations.  And I have find little annoying problem. I need to get my input number in one line, but when i use

```
sc = new Scanner(System.in);        
sc.useLocale(Locale.US);

System.out.print("a=");
double a = sc.nextDouble();

System.out.print(", b=");
double b = sc.nextDouble();
```

I get something like this:

```
a=Some Number
, b=Some Number
```

But I need this(to be an the same line):

```
a=Some Number, b=Some Number
```

I have tried to find the answer but after 4 hours I can't find it or I don't understand it. Thanks for help.

Comment: Why not fetch the input and then format it in one line?

Answer (score 1):

You would do so:

```
double a = sc.nextDouble();
double b = sc.nextDouble();
System.out.print("a=" + a + ",b=" + b);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
double a = sc.nextDouble();
double a = sc.nextDouble();
 System.out.print("a ="+ a + ","+ "b ="+b );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);        
sc.useLocale(Locale.US);
double a = sc.nextDouble();
double b = sc.nextDouble();
System.out.println("a="+a+"b="+b);
```